# Can a pilot drive an ultralight with folded wings on the shouder of a country road

Tags: usa, faa

Saw an ultralight with power driven wheels the other day.

This begs the question, can a pilot legally slowly drive an ultralight with folded wings stationary prop and powered wheels on the shoulder of a country road, say with a slow moving vehicle sign?

Comment: Probably.  But you won't know for sure until a cop stops you.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a Federal Aviation Regulation that governs this?

Comment: That would be a "motor vehicle". There are rules for operating a motor vehicle on the public roads, even the shoulder. All states have different rules, regarding potential max speed or horsepower.

Comment: Something like that happened in Australia. To the pub, naturally: https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-29876001

Comment: Love it @Ben, but the eejit left the engine running! What a complete moron!

Comment: Because if you are going to drive an unlicensed vehicle which is also a plane on the road, obviously it's better to do it drunk.

Answer (score 2):

The FAA has no jurisdiction over the roadways.  It would depend on the locality, but it is reasonable to presume that in a rural area that permits non-street legal machines like farm tractors, ATVs, etc. would similarly allow an ultralight.

Comment: As an example, from the Virginia DMV: "Farm vehicle license plates issued by the Department of Motor Vehicles may be used on a vehicle used for farming purposes by anyone who owns, rents, or operates a farm of a size that reasonably requires the use of such a vehicle to transport agricultural products."

So farm vehicle is not an automatic "get out of jail free" card.